# Laravel Searchform and Delete not working

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a search form for offices and delete for offices, also edit it those 2 were working before. But after I changed and fix edit form and button those are not working anymore the search is not working it shows this error

`Undefined variable: building (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\search.blade.php)`

The delete also show this error but it works after I go back to the office page it deleted it but it shows an error message:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\building.blade.php)
```

DD offices result

[image]
This is the controller for search and delete

OfficeController.php

```
    public function index()
    {

        $search = \Request::get('search');
$offices = Office::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')->get(); 
return view('search',compact('offices','search'));

      }

    public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $office = new Office();
        $office->name =$request->officename;
        $office->floor = $request->floor;
        $office->building_id = $id;
        $office->save();

         \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Created successfully!');

        return redirect()->route('building', $id);

    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $office = Office::find($id);
        return view('office')->withOffice($office);
    }


   public function edit($id, $office_id) {

        $office = Office::find($office_id);
        return view('editoffice', compact('office', 'id'));
}

    public function update(Request $request, $id, $office_id)
    {
           // echo $id.'--'.$office_id;exit;
        //$office = Office::find($id); 
      $office = Office::find($office_id);
        $office->name = $request->officename;
        $office->floor = $request->floor;
        $office->update();

      \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Updated successfully!');

         return redirect()->route('building', $id);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $office = Office::find($id);
        $office->delete();
        \Session::flash('building_flash_delete', 'Deleted successfully!');
         return redirect()->route('building', $id);

    }
}
```

search.blade.php

No error in search when I remove this

`<a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>`

```
<div class="search">

          {!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'offices','role'=>'search']) !!}
        <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Search
           </button>
          </span>
            </div>
             {!! Form::close()!!}

           </div>
              <hr>
        <table class="table">

          <thead>
              <th>Office Name</th>
              <th>Belongs to</th>
              <th>Office Floor</th>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            @foreach($offices as $office)
              <tr>
                <td>{{optional($office)->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->building->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->floor}}</td>

                <td class="a">

                    @if(!Auth::guest())

                  <a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
                  <a href="{{route('deleteoffice', $office->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
                  @endif

            @endforeach

        @endsection
```

I also have Building.php in app folder it has code like this

```
class Building extends Model
{
    public $table = 'buildings';

    public function offices(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Office');
    }
}
```

Office.php

```
class Office extends Model
{
    public function building(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Building');
    }
}
```

ROUTES

```
Route::get('/', 'BuildingController@index')->name('index');

Route::get('building/{id}', 'PageController@show')->name('building');

Route::get('office/{id}', 'OfficeController@show')->name('officeMenu');

Route::get('offices', 'OfficeController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

  Route::get('buildings/create', 'BuildingController@create')->name('createbform');

  Route::post('building/create/store', 'BuildingController@saveBuilding')->name('createbuilding');

  Route::get('building/{id}/edit', 'BuildingController@edit');

  Route::post('building/{id}/edit', 'BuildingController@update')->name('editbuilding');

  Route::get('building/{id}/delete', 'BuildingController@destroy');

  Route::get('building/{id}/offices/create', 'OfficeController@create')->name('createofficeform');

  Route::post('building/{id}/offices/create/store', 'OfficeController@store')->name('createoffice');

Route::get('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@edit')->name('editofficeform');

Route::post('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@update')->name('editoffice');

  Route::get('offices/{id}/delete', 'OfficeController@destroy')->name('deleteoffice');
});
```

buildidng.blade.php

```
  <div class="officebg">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">


        <div class="Bldgttl">

          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <img src="{{URL::to('/assets')}}/{{$building->picture}}" alt="" style="height:300px; width:500px;">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  {{$building->name}}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

            <div class="rows">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

              <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">

      @if(!Auth::guest())
                    <a href="{{route('createofficeform', $building->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Create an Office</a>
      @endif
            </div>

              {!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'offices','role'=>'search']) !!}
            <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
              <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
             <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Search</i>
               </button>
              </span>
                </div>
                 {!! Form::close()!!}


            <table class="table">
              <div class="ttitle">
              <thead>
                  <th>Office Name</th>
                  <th>Office Floor</th>
              </thead>


              <tbody>
                @foreach($offices as $office)
                  <tr>

                    <td>{{optional($office)->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$office->floor}}</td>
                    <td class="a">

                      @if(!Auth::guest())

                      <a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
                      <a href="{{route('deleteoffice', $office->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
                      @endif
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          </div>
            @endsection
```

Comment: Can you post web.php?? And the file  building.blade.php?It seems that your search file cannot access building. Try $this->belongsTo(\App\Building::class);

Comment: There it is take a look routes @Rajesh Paudel

Comment: You have and error in `building.blade.php` .. where is the code of this file?

Comment: Ok i posted it above @Felippe Duarte

Answer (score 0):

Your building.blade.php is trying to access the $building variable. Your show method in your controller is only passing $office as data. Since $building doesn't exist trying to get the name property of it is returning an error.

You need to either pass $building from the controller to the view, or if it is part of $office extrapolate $building from that variable.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    $building = Buildng::where('id', '=', $office->building_id)->firstOrFail();
    return view('office',compact('office', 'building'));
}
```

Comment: How to do this? @Rick Calder

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='   Theres something wrong with the = @Rick Calder

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.5 @Rick Calder

Comment: ah, crap, once sec.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the actual get on the end.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'   it keeps giving me this , your code seems right @Rick Calder

Comment: I missed the closing bracket on the last line... fixed.

Comment: I also missed the brackets inside the compact. Good god this was a mess, sorry about that. The code should work now.

Comment: I can only see white screen no results @Rick Calder

Comment: instead of I can see the tab named as what office im looking for the tab name shows the link like this one `http://localhost:8000/offices?search=Case`  @Rick Calder

Comment: Still shows the whitescreen Ive used dd same result as shown above screenshot @Rick Calder

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `building` defined in `show`.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    return view('office')->withOffice($office);
}
```

What you can do is to load a building in show method

```
public function show($id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    $building = Building::first();//some logic to find building
    return view('office',['building' => $building, 'office' => $office]);
}
```

Comment: public function show($id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    $building = Building::first();//some logic to find building
    return view('office',['building' => $building])->withOffice($office);
}   it shows a blank page  @Felippe Duarte

Comment: still the same, a white page @Felippe Duarte